# How to let the application rollback when browser is closed during the half way?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I try to stop the data storing to database if the browser is closed half way for my web application.

For example:

After click Submit button, during the process, someone close the browser window or internet connection is down. I want the application to rollback all the committed data. Is that possible to do that in application without changing configuration in the store procedure?

Comment: I think that this is a very rare case, except if your process to save the data takes too long, that this is not the normal case. So did the save data takes too long that there is a possibility the user close the browser before they finish the save ?

Answer (score 0):

No - this is not possible in any normal way without creating the ultimate hack of a solution.

Normally in a case like this data is committed in stages. If they never 'complete' the next step, their prior data is removed by some process at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an idea base on `Response.IsClientConnected` that say you if the user is still connected.

I think that the **sql command to insert data is too fast** that you never catch it, how ever if sql command is not so fast you can try it, even tho I suggest to find a different way to apply long time takes sql transactions. Also if the user stops the connection to the page an exceptions also thrown.

```
    BEGIN Tran       

    ...Sql Command...

    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        ...Commit....
    }
    else
    {
        ...Rollback....
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how you are performing your data access.  If you are using .NET I'd do some research on System.Transactions.TransactionScope().  This is an alternative to transactions, as mention previously, in sql and is only dependent upon your data access layer implementation (e.g. Entity Framework or Linq to SQL vs. Stored Procedures or plain T-SQL)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Beyond this suggestion, it's up to you as the developer to control edge cases such as these.  For example if the user is mid-way in a multi-step process; it is here the business rules and use cases define how you are to handle such scenarios.  Implementing transactional state might be an option where some dismiss the scrap data others save it just in case the user returns.  Given this, I'd say this is potentially a design issue rather than a development issue.

I hope this helps. Cheers!